# Construct $\zeta (s)$ from $\Gamma (s)$ and elementary functions

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

Riemann's functional equation allows $\Gamma (s)$ to be expressed as a **finite** composition of [elememtary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) and zeta functions:
$$\Gamma (1-s)=\frac{\pi ^{1-s}\zeta (s)}{2^s \sin (\pi s/2)\zeta (1-s)},\quad 1-s\in\mathbb{C}.$$

Conversely, is there an equation which allows $\zeta (s)$ to be expressed as a finite composition of elementary functions and gamma functions?

Comment: Of course no, $\zeta(s)$ is a complicated function.

Comment: @reuns Could that somehow be mathematically justified?

Comment: You cannot really relate $\zeta(s)$ with some other elementary function. I recommend you reading some literature on Riemann Zeta function to understand it's complexity. We know very little about $\zeta(2n + 1)$, we hardly even know anything about $\zeta(3)$.

Comment: The asymptotic of $\zeta(s)$ is too erratic to be obtained from elementary and $\Gamma$ functions.

Comment: @BooleanWick I know it's 'complex' but I still wonder whether there exists an equation relating it to the elementary functions and the gamma function.

Comment: @Nomas I don't think so. Maybe you should give a try to get one :)